# How to restart a Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I logged into a Linux machine with its IP address, using putty, and entered shutdown command in home directory instead of in tomcat bin.

The session got closed and I am unable to re-login into the Linux server from putty.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Not enough information to help here other than "power the machine on again" - how you do this varies wildly based on the bits you didn't include.

Comment: Let me guess...you used `shutdown` and not `reboot`? Well, the machine's off now. Power it back on...

Comment: Working as root for tasks that shouldn't have needed it? Otherwise, how would you have been allowed to use the shutdown command when trying to manage a service from your home directory? And do you have `.` as the first directory in your `PATH`? Otherwise why would `shutdown` have run a different command depending on the current directory? Each of the two on its own is a mistake. The combination could be even worse.

Answer (score 5):

Your server is powered down, so you push the power button. Real servers will allow you to do this via an out-of-band management interface such as Dell's drac or HP's iLO. Servers without such out-of-band management should be connected to a managed power switch so you can powercycle them. Of course that only helps if the server is set to boot automatically when power is restored.

Of course, if it's a virtual server, you can simply log in to the physical host and use the relevant tool to power the VM back on again (how this works is different for each virtualization solution).

Answer (score 3):

`shutdown` shuts the server down, `reboot` reboots the server.

Turn the server back on.